How to interoperate from clojure with java varargs methods
According with docs I have to use into-array but it doesn't work.
(java.nio.file.Paths/get (into-array ["myfolder" "aaa.txt"]))
; Execution error (ClassCastException) at msm.config/eval10595 (form-init12148349852569231555.clj:153).
; class [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to class java.net.URI ([Ljava.lang.String; and java.net.URI are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

So, I am not completely understand how to do it...

You might want to use the path function in babashka.fs for this.

Paths/get
does not take just an array.  It takes a first string argument before the array.  This signals, that at least one argument is needed.  And while this looks nice when used in Java, it is a little meh on the JVM side.
(java.nio.file.Paths/get "/tmp" (into-array ["a" "b" "c"]))
; #object[sun.nio.fs.UnixPath 0x3e792ce3 "/tmp/a/b/c"]


Oh, right. It makes perfect sense.  Thanks a lot!
